# Add Icons to Excel cells using OfficeJS

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, conditional-formatting, excel-web-addins

I am trying to build a web-addin for Excel using OfficeJS.

I've added Icons to a range of cells using the following code.

```
async function addIcon() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const range = sheet.getRange("A1:E13");
    const conditionalFormat = range.conditionalFormats
        .add(Excel.ConditionalFormatType.iconSet);
    const iconSetCF = conditionalFormat.iconSet;
    iconSetCF.style = Excel.IconSet.threeFlags;
    iconSetCF.showIconOnly=false;
    iconSetCF.criteria = [
        {
            type: Excel.ConditionalFormatIconRuleType.number,
            operator: Excel.ConditionalIconCriterionOperator.greaterThanOrEqual,
            formula: ">0"
        }
    ];

    await context.sync();
});
}
```

The above code adds different icons for each of the cell values as shown in the images.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

**Can someone please answer the following questions?**

**Question1:**
**Can we set the color of the Icon to a single color?**
I don't want to have different colors of the same Icon but want to set it to either Yellow or Red.

**Question2:
Can the Icon be applied to non-numeric cells?**

As of now the icon is only applied to those cells with numeric values, and all the properties of the `Excel.ConditionalFormatIconRuleType` are either number,Formula, percentile etc, which are useful only for numeric values.

I have tried the following code, but doesn't work.

```
iconSetCF.criteria = [
            {
                type: Excel.ConditionalFormatIconRuleType.Formula,
                operator: Excel.ConditionalIconCriterionOperator.greaterThanOrEqual,
                formula: "=ISTEXT(A1)"
            }
        ];
```

**Question3:
Can we add custom icons instead of using the predefined iconSet?**

Can I use a custom image as an Icon instead of using the office predefined icons?
I tried to use the `Excel.ConditionalFormatType.custom` property but it can only apply colors or format the cells but cannot add any images inside the cells.

Kindly let me know your thoughts on the above questions? I couldn't find anything related to my above requirements in the OfficeJS's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG, PNG, and SVG images can be inserted into a worksheet as shapes. The `ShapeCollection.addImage` method takes a base64-encoded string as an argument. This is either a JPEG or PNG image in string form. `ShapeCollection.addSvg` also takes in a string, though this argument is XML that defines the graphic.

The following code sample shows an image file being loaded by a FileReader as a string. The string has the metadata "base64," removed before the shape is created.

```
// This sample creates an image as a Shape object in the worksheet.
let myFile = document.getElementById("selectedFile");
let reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (event) => {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        let startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
        let myBase64 = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);
        let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("MyWorksheet");
        let image = sheet.shapes.addImage(myBase64);
        image.name = "Image";
        return context.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
};

// Read in the image file as a data URL.
reader.readAsDataURL(myFile.files[0]);
```

And if you need to reposition images you need do the following (implemented in the requirement set 1.10):

```
Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("MyWorksheet");
    let cell = sheet.getRange("D5")
    cell.load('top,left') //pre-load top and left
    let myBase64 = "your bas64string here";
    const shape = sheet.shapes.addImage(myBase64)

    await context.sync()

    shape.incrementLeft(cell.left) // <- left
    shape.incrementTop(cell.top) // <-top
    await context.sync();
})
```